# Set tab with jquery forcefully

Tags: jquery

I am trying to automatically set the active tab by using this.

```
<li class="tabs_item 2tab" id="tabSurgery2">
  <a href="#page-5" class="">
    <span>OPP</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

```js
// THIS WILL BE FOR A REFRESH PAGE 
// TO RE-SET THE ACTIVE TAB
var tab = "#" + getParameterByName('tabloc');  // tabSurgery2
$('.cssmenu ul li a.active_pat_tab').removeClass('active_pat_tab');
$(tab).closest('a').addClass('active_pat_tab');

//THIS WORKS FOR THE CLICK EVENT
$('.cssmenu ul li a').click(function() {
  $('.cssmenu ul li a.active_pat_tab').removeClass('active_pat_tab');
  $(this).closest('.cssmenu ul li a').addClass('active_pat_tab');
});
```

Comment: Tab variable holds `#tabSurgery2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `tab` variable holds the selector for the parent `li`, you need to use `find()` to go down the DOM tree, not `closest()` to go back up it. Try this:

```
$('.cssmenu ul li a.active_pat_tab').removeClass('active_pat_tab');
$("#" + getParameterByName('tabloc')).find('a').addClass('active_pat_tab');
```